# How to combine image slices into a NIfTI file

Tags: python, nifti, nibabel

I have a function which, given a NIfTI file, generates a set of images. How can I essentially reverse that process with another function which takes in these images and creates a NIfTI file from them?

Comment: NIftI file includes more than mere images, Pixel spacing, Affine transform, etc.., please refer to [Nibabel Nifti header](https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html#the-nifti-header)

Answer (score 0):

You do that with SimpleITK's ImageSeriesReader class.  It'd look something like this:

```
import SimpleITK as sick

reader = sitk.ImageSeriesReader()

reader.SetFileNames(["slice1.png", ..., "sliceN.png"])

volume_image = reader.Execute()
```

Note that the volume won't have any voxel spacing information, so you might need to call the SetSpacing method

```
volume_image.SetSpacing([x_spacing, y_spacing, z_spacing])
```